# How to pass control's value to services

Tags: angularjs

I have button, on save button I need to pass values of all controls to the services.
I have written service code as well, my query is how to pass all values to factory method.

Help me out how to send data in given model?

This is my Model Class:

```
public class FavouriteSearch
     {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Cols> ColList{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my local Controller code:

```
$scope.favSearchSave = function () {
var favSearchItemList = [];
$scope.searchName = this.searchName; 
favouriteSearchRepository.saveFavouriteSearch(favSearchItemList).then(
function (result) {
if(result)
notificationService.showType("success", "Favorite search is successfully saved", "");
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
 $scope.showFavSearchModal = false;
        };
```

I am using angular Modal so I need to save values on popup save button .

**UI code:**

```
<modal-body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" style="width:100% !important" ng-model 
               ="searchName" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </modal-body>
 <modal-footer>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="favSearchSave()">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="favSearchCancel()">Cancel</button>
 </modal-footer>
```

Comment: Can you add your remaining code, like the form which you are using?

Comment: I added model class code. Issue is how to get value of popup modal's textbox in local controller. It is undefined now.

Answer (score 0):

If using an modal aka ui-bootstrap modal you handle saving of data in two ways. Once the user clicks save then in the modals save method you can pass the object to the service. Or in the resolve when you close the modal you have a promise handling successful save clicks.

Either way is fine, there are arguments about testability ease when passing the service to the modal, but again fine either way.

To pass to the service have a method to set and pass an object. Inside the service have a private variable that holds the object you wish to keep. Add a get method to fetch the object from other locations.

Simple and classic angular 1 paradigm for communicating btw controller, services, directives, components.

Answer (score 0):

It will helpful to you

here I have created an Object called `$scope.c`and pushed it into saveObject Incase saveObject is an Object  no need to make push.

```js
 var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
    app.service('favSearchRepo',function(){
      this.saveFavouriteSearch=function(obj){
          console.log(obj)
      };
    })
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,favSearchRepo){
        $scope.c={};
        $scope.favSearchSave = function () {
            var saveObject = [];
             saveObject.push($scope.c)
            favSearchRepo.saveFavouriteSearch(saveObject);
            /*notificationService.showType("success", "it is successfully saved", "");*/
            //$scope.showFavSearchModal = false;
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.one">
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.two">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="favSearchSave()">
    </div>
```